# Not found module saml2 while Installing HUE on ubuntu hadoop standalone

Tags: python, hadoop, makefile, hue

Ive installed the package libsaml and still the make fails.  I'm new to python, the absolute paths stuff, the python module stuff in general, but I want to learn it! 
 Any tips would be appreciated!  Thanks ahead of time.

The last couple lines of code in the /Hue/ "make apps" is this:

```
Installed /home/hadoop/hue/desktop/libs/indexer/srcmake[2]: Leaving directory /home/hadoop/hue/desktop/libs/indexer'
Regenerating database at /home/hadoop/hue/desktop/desktop.db
Syncing/updating database at /home/hadoop/hue/desktop/desktop.db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 41, in entry
 from desktop import settings, appmanager
  File "/home/hadoop/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/settings.py", line 212, in <module>
_lib_conf_modules = [dict(module=app.conf, config_key=None) for app in appmanager.DESKTOP_LIBS if app.conf is not None]
File "/home/hadoop/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/appmanager.py", line 174, in conf
return self._submodule("conf")
File "/home/hadoop/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/appmanager.py", line 193, in _submodule
return _import_module_or_none(self.module.__name__ + "." + name)
File "/home/hadoop/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/appmanager.py", line 53, in _import_module_or_none
__import__(module)
File "/home/hadoop/hue/desktop/libs/libsaml/src/libsaml/conf.py", line 23, in <module>
import saml2
ImportError: No module named saml2
make[1]: *** [/home/hadoop/hue/desktop/desktop.db] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/hadoop/hue/desktop'
make: *** [desktop] Error 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the updated version.  I got it working without a pull actually,  found it via google.  here is part of the solution I used wget http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/download/xmlsec1-1.2.20.tar.gz    apt-get install libltdl-dev (make & configure)  then I ran:  apt-get install swig-devel  and build/env/bin/pip install -e git+https://github.com/abec/pysaml2@HEAD#egg=pysaml2
sudo build/env/bin/pip install -e git+https://github.com/abec/djangosaml2@HEAD#egg=djangosaml2

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed a few minutes ago with https://github.com/cloudera/hue/commit/326eccd89cb2e4d3c3d5c07ab14fb0fde21858da, could you rebase on master?